# Плагин фото галереи для django

Tags: django, ckeditor

Здравствуйте. Существуют ли в природе плагины для создания фото галереи для Django? Пользуюсь ckeditor`ом. Может есть плагин для него? На официальном сайте не нашел, да и гугл особо не помогает в этом вопросе.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ckeditor не особо связан с галереей на сайте.

Если вам надо отображать картинки, прикреплённые ckeditor'ом к какой-то статье, предположим, то вам проще взять какую-то клиентскую библиоеку для просмотра картинок, например, [prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/), основанную на JQuery

Если же цель именно сделать полноценную галерею для картинок, то есть множество сторонних галерей, список можно посмотреть на сайте [djangopackages](https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/gallery/), например.

Ну и если ничего из вышеперечисленного не подходит, то всегда можно написать своё решение

Comment: FeroxTL, снова Вы спасли меня! Вы волшебный человек) Поставил photologue.